# How to forward traffic on various ports through a wireguard vpn using iptables/ufw

Tags: linux, proxy, iptables, wireguard

I have 2 machines running ubuntu 22.04, we will call them server and proxy. The proxy is a vps with an static public ip, and the server is running behind a nat. I want to route all traffic on some ports on the proxy to the server.

I have set up a wireguard vpn beetween the 2 and both can ping each other, if i curl the vpn adress of the server from the proxy i get the correct html response, and setting up nginx on the proxy (which is not the intended final solution cause i would like to route other services that aren't http/https) allows me to proxy_pass to the vpn ip and once agin get correct html response.

But i haven't been able to set up the forward using iptables/ufw. This is my wiregaurd configuration that includes the iptables routing rules on interface up.

Proxy:

```
[Interface]
# Proxy with static ip
Address = 10.250.0.1/32
ListenPort = 23456
PrivateKey = {private key}
# packet forwarding
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# port forwarding
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.250.0.2
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.250.0.2
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.250.0.2
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.250.0.2
      
[Peer]
# main_server behind nat
PublicKey = {pub key}
AllowedIPs = 10.250.0.2/32
```

Server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.250.0.2/32
ListenPort = 23456
PrivateKey = {priv key}

[Peer]
PublicKey = {pub key}
Endpoint = {proxy server ip}:23456
AllowedIPs = 10.250.0.0/16
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Running  `sudo iptables-save -c`
returns the following

```
# Completed on Wed Aug 24 17:01:57 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Aug 24 17:01:57 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
[0:0] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.250.0.2
[4:208] -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.250.0.2
COMMIT
```

With the number of packets and bytes `[4:208]` increasing everytime i try to access the proxy via web browser

Comment: Did you find a solution ?